# How to pipe data from one stream method to another

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I'm using a client libray for reading and writing files from a remote host (`Renci.SshNet.Sftp`).  Both the upload and download methods are active - they consume a stream, they don't return a Stream for later writing:

```
void SftpFile.UploadFile(Stream input, String path);    // Reads from input and uploads
void SftpFile.DownloadFile(Stream output, String path); // Downloads and writes to output
```

I want to download a file and upload it to another location.

The restrictions I have are:

1. Direct peer-to-peer transfer using other parts of the library isn't possible due to firewall restrictions
2. Caching in-between is a bad idea because I can't guarantee to have enough space.
3. I need to monitor the progress to report back to the user.

AFAIK I'm left with the option of running two threads and piping / buffering data between them (see producer / consumer problem).

This isn't an uncommon design problem.  I've hit it several times in other languages such as Java.  But this is the first time I've hit it in c#.  In other languages I've been forced to write my own `Stream` class to act as a pipe / buffer between the two threads and take care of synchronisation.

Does c# have anything to deal with this problem already?  OR Does anyone know of any third party libraries which solve the problem?

Comment: Will the PipeStream class be of any use? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream(v=vs.110).aspx